# How do I use variables in if...then... statements in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement

In C++ how do you use variables in if...then... or if...else or if... statements?

Here's what I mean.

When I enter something like this to make a calculator or something:

```
int main()
{
  signed int a, b, c, d, e result;
  cin >> a;
  cin >> b;
  cin >> c;
  cin >> d;
  cin >> e;

  if(d=="+")
    if(e=="-")
      result = a + b - c
  cout <<result;
}
```

It doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `d` is an integer, not a string. Same goes for `e`.

Comment: For better results when asking questions, please post the full compiler errors and point out which lines they're on.

Comment: So how should I solve this problem?

Comment: It might be best to pick up a good book on C++ and a cup of coffee and read up on the basics for a while.

Comment: Okay, when running the code it randomly ends at line eight. I do not know what is wrong. I mean on the below code.

Answer (score 0):

As chris says, you can't compare a string literal to an integer.

If you want to compare to a single char (I'm guessing that's where you're heading), you want to use single quotes, like so `if(d == '+')`. Single quotes for chars, double quotes add an implicit zero-termination on strings. So "+" is actually {'+', 0x0}

Comment: Whoops, I'm sorry, I didn't notice. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, when running the code it randomly ends at line eight. I do not know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
signed int a, b, c,result;
char d,e;
  cin >> a;
  cin >> b;
  cin >> c;
  cin >> d;
  cin >> e;

if(d=='+')
  if(e=='-')
    result = a + b - c
cout <<result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing a character with a variable you have to use a single quote around the character.
For e.g

char mychar='a';

if (mychar=='a')

cout<<"its a" ;

Answer (score 0):

```
if(d > 0) {

}

if(e < 0) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
int a, b, c,result; // you don't need write signed because it's by default signed
char d,e;
  cin >> a;
  cin >> b;
  cin >> c;
  cin >> d;
  cin >> e;

if(d=='+'){ // good practice to put {}. if you'll put another line of code in the future 
  if(e=='-'){
    result = a + b - c; //you forgot statement ";" 
   }
}
cout <<result;
```